# how to say c compiler they are hex value

Tags: c

I am trying to write checksum evaluator. I have wrote below code ;

```
0xFF -
    (  (
        0x10 + 0x01 +0x00+  0x13+  0xa2+ 0x00+ 0x40+  0x4a+
            0xfd + 0x15 + 0xff + 0xfe+ 0x00+ 0x08 +
                ( 1 + 30 ) +
                ( 2 + 30 )
           )
   & 0xFF
 )
```

see the line ( 1 + 30 ) and ( 2 + 30 ), they are converted to hex value but while addition they are converted, and the result is not expected. Are there any way to say ( 1 + 30 ) is hex value my c compiler brother ?

Comment: try 0x1 and 0x1e? or if they're really hex values, then simply add the 0x part: 0x1 and 0x30.

Comment: @MarcB 0x1 != 1 because 1 hexa value is 31. If I write variable l instead of 1. How can I solve ?

Comment: so say they're string chars and not integers... either way, you should be able to trivially figure out what the ascii value of a character is and represent it in hex. that's basic programming 101.

Comment: @MarcB say int x ;(x is always digit) I am taking data from other place, so I do not know value of x. How can I put x in place of 1

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Remember that a number is just a number, and "hexadecimal" and "decimal" are two different ways of inputting or outputting numbers, or converting them from and to strings of characters.  `int x;` is neither decimal nor hexadecimal.

Comment: 0 + '1' is decimal 31. Use single quote to have a char.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the compiler to use `30` as hexa decimal value then mention it with `0x`. Like `(0x1 + 0x30) + (0x2 + 0x30)`

`int a` - here `a` can store values of `+2^31` to `-(2^31-1)`, its range is not `0` to `9`. `a` always stores the values in binary format. We can print it in any format like decimal, hex or octal. `printf("%d, %x, %o", a, a, a);`

So if you want to use variable `a` in the place of `30`. use like below.

```
int a = 0x30; //or int a = 48; 48 is the decimal representation of 0x30
....
(0x1 + a)
....
```

Dont confuse much with hexadecimal values. Its just a representation of a value. If you have a 10 pen, you can say like

- I have `10`  pens in decimal format
- I have `0xA` pens in hexadecimal format
- I have `12`  pens in octal format

Comment: If I want use varible a ( int a, a always digit 0-9) How can I put a in the place of 1 ? Can I write 0xa